# node.js - overloading functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, overloading

Is there a way to overload functions in node.js similar to [__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like bxjx briefly mentioned, Node.js is based on Google's V8 javascript engine, meaning that any language constructs or features come from that. Seeing as it is non-standard, i don't think they will add it in the near future. Also i don't think Node will ever base itself on a non-official V8 fork, but who knows. You can still use that fork yourself.

Comment: Yeah, a bit annoying having to build on a fork.

Answer (score 1):

That would be cool. It would open up DSL like capabilities found in ruby.

According to [this conversation on the node.js google group](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/622a22ca9ef66e53/56c2790ab545f643?#56c2790ab545f643), it's probably not going to happen. I can't think of another way around it without object.send('method'), but maybe it's possible.

Looks like people have [forked V8 to add this sort of thing](http://github.com/dachev/v8).