# auto-exporting functions in a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

is it possible to export automatically all the functions defined in a module of node.js?

**Example:**

Let's say that in the file `foobar.js` I have the following two functions

```
function foo() {
    ...
}

function bar() {
    ...
}
```

Does exist a tool for adding them automatically to the `exports` dictionary so that the following code is made possible?

```
foobar = require('foobar.js')
foobar.foo(); // works, even if not explicitly added in 'exports'
foobar.bar(); // also works
```

In other words, I would like to add progressively new functions to the module and not having to add them manually to the export dictionary. So, the following is what I want to **avoid**:

```
exports.foo = foo;
exports.bar = bar;
```

Maybe this could be achieved by getting introspectively the list of all the functions defined in the module, but I also don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A way to expose things in a module:

```
var foobar = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};
module.exports = foobar;
```

In your case:

```
foobar = require('foobar.js');
module.exports = foobar;
```

You can read extra [here](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/).

## edit

doing what you need would require to overload node "require" method and this is not possible, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811408/node-js-overloading-functions).
Maybe you can install [node-overload](https://github.com/bmeck/node-overload) and use method **RePrototype**.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what I meant is a way to add *automatically* the functions defined in the module to the `exports`

Comment: last chance: try node-overload